# Поиск диапазона чисел в mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

Есть таблица в *mongodb*, следующего формата

```
{
    "_id" : "14",
    "Command" : "some text",
    "Content" : "some text"
}
```

Поле *_id* формата *String*. Как осуществлять поиск диапазона чисел в такой таблице с помощью C# (да и в самом *mongo* тоже не получается)?
Вот как я пытаюсь искать

```
var filter = Query.And(Query<FT.MogoBase.Commands>.GTE(l => l._id, from),
            Query<FT.MogoBase.Commands>.LT(l => l._id, to));
var ret = collectionCommands.Find(filter).ToList();
```

*_id* в базе *String* формата, а мне надо искать как *int*.

В mongodb выходит следующий вид

```
{ "_id" : { "$gte" : 2, "$lt" : 5475 } }
```

Но естественно так ничего не находит.

Comment: Если ваши _id — на самом деле числа, то почему вы их храните в виде строк?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `mongoshell` вы можете отобрать следующей инструкцией:

```
db.test.find("this._id > 2 && this._id < 5475")
```

или

```
db.test.find( { $where: function() { return (parseInt(this._id) > 2 && parseInt(this._id) < 5475) } } );
```

В этом запросе поле будет автоматически преобразовано в число. Это повлияет на производительность выполнения каждого запроса. Также при таком запросе не будут использоваться индексы.

Но лучше всего преобразовать поле `_id` в число. Вы же по нему ищите как по числу. Сравнение строкового типа выполняется по другим правилам.

Преобразовать можно следующим скриптом в основной таблице:

```
db.test.find().snapshot().forEach(function(doc) { 
    var id = doc._id; 
    doc._id = new NumberInt(id); 
    db.test.insert(doc); 
    db.test.remove({_id : id}); 
})
```

и в ссылающейся на нее:

```
db.test2.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    var intVal = new NumberInt(doc.extid);
    db.test2.update(
        {_id: doc._id}, 
        {$set: {extid: intVal}}
    );
})
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Comment: Именно в подобной ситуации, что вы используете  ["bulk"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk) API

Answer (score 1):

Как говорилось в предыдущем ответе Лушее вариант преобразовать поле `_id` в число. Лучший способ сделать это; это с помощью ["Bulk"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk) API для максимальной эффективности.

```js
var bulk = db.test.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var count = 0; 
db.test.find().forEach(function(doc) { 
    bulk.find({ "_id" : doc._id }).removeOne(); 
    doc._id = parseInt(doc._id); 
    bulk.insert(doc); 
    count++;
    if(count % 100 == 0) {
        // выполнить каждые 100 операций и повторного инициализации
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.test.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
} )


if(count > 0) {
    // очистить очереди
    bulk.execute();
}
```

Теперь можно писать запрос:

```js
db.test({ "_id" : { "$gte" : 2, "$lt" : 5475 } })
```

Comment: В данной ситуации можно использовать initializeUnorderedBulkOp(). Будет работать параллельно, что увеличит скорость. Данный функционал поддерживается начиная с версии 2.6.

Comment: Да можно но здесь я хочу остановить запрос если что то не так. да с версии 2.6 сейчас 3.0 и скоро 3.2 :-) Мне кажется что надо учить люди новые методы